# Restricting the Assigned To column in TFS Work Item from being Same as Creator

Tags: tfs

I am trying to request a  code review in TFS. The developer creates a work item and assigns to anybody in the team asking for a review.

Here, I just want to make sure none of the developers should be able to create a WI  assigned to himself/herself (by creating a Task WI). It should go to only other people in the team.
Is there any way I can edit the WI feature.

I know there is a field "Assigned To" . Is there any way I can edit this field to prevent to assign to the current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`NOTSAMEAS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194953.aspx) rule to prevent it from been the same value as the `CreatedBy` field (assuming that it is set as `READONLY`).

Example:

```
<NOTSAMEAS field="System.CreatedBy" />
```