# Is it possible in TFS 2013 that only the author of a Work Item is able to change the Status to "Done"?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

The company I work for just started using Team Foundation Server 2013 and it is my Task, to find answers for the open questions in our Team. By doing so, I found a problem I can't solve.

Is it possible, that only the `author/creator` of a Work Item is able to change the `Status` of a Work Item to `Done`?

The advantage of this would be, that Tasks can only be closed when the author is satisfied with the Result.

Comment: Why would the creator move to Done? Done means that the development team says it is complete.

Comment: This is mainly for the aspect that the Author wants to "check" if the results are what he expected or needs.
The development team would in that case use the assigned to field after they finished their work to assign the author so that he/she can check and say "done" or "i need something more"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By editing the work item definitions, you can achieve this.
[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024921/how-can-i-restrict-a-transition-in-the-workflow-to-only-the-user-that-created-th/26031472#comment40814950_26031472) asked earlier and you'll just have to use the question's answer in the transition to **Done** state for you.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the Link to the original question. Seems as if i have not looked close enough on questions that are already asked.