# How to forbid transition from one state to another for person who made work item in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: xml, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

The point is that I want to forbid transition from Resolved state to QA for person who made work item and is making transition. This transition must be done by someone else for reason because it means that is checked and it is ready for testing.

It should look something like this...

**TRANSITION from="Resolved" to="QA" 
    not="[project]\Me(or something like currentuser)"**

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that we can create a dynamic limitation for a group or user in transition. You may use one of the following ways:

1. Create group that can move from Resolve to QA and use it in clause `for` in transition.
2. Create a custom control for a work item form that will control your process and restrict transition for a user that created wi.
3. Create an external application that will return wi to previous state if it does not meet your rules.

Comment: Number 2 is solution I need. I already tried with Syste.CreatedBy but it uses

Comment: Number 2 is solution I need. I already tried with System.CreatedBy field but it uses <COPY ="currentuser". When I change user it shows the person who is logged in and not person who created task. It seems like there is no way to create this permission because it works with groups and single user. Do you have any idea how to fool this?? I found this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024921/how-can-i-restrict-a-transition-in-the-workflow-to-only-the-user-that-created-th]. Even though title is exactly as my problem, the result is not... Sorry for previous comment.

Comment: As custom controls, I mean something like that [Add a custom control to the work item form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/custom-control?view=azure-devops). So you can (through the work item form) control your transitions. But this way will not work with kanban or scrum boards. Your link is interesting but its not your case. Because (as I see) they created a rule that enable to close only for user who created a work item. We can use `System.CreatedBy` and some custom field `Custom.HiWantsToQA`, but we can not check equality of one field to another.